# How could I do DateTime.Now.Date (from C#) in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, datetime

In C# I can use

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Now.Date;
```

This will give the current date, without the TimeSpan value (***'00:00:00'***). In JavaScript I did this:

```
var dt = new Date(new Date().getFullYear(), new Date().getMonth(), new Date().getDate());
```

But is so "ugly" that there must be a better, easier and clean way to do it.

Comment: That is ugly, why would you call `new Date(...)` 4 times?

Comment: Also, DateTime.Now is usually used in C# (as it's static property, no need to create new object)

Comment: @Jesse Thanks, I was in a hurry and didn't use copy and paste. Thanks a lot for correct this silly mistake ^_^

Comment: do you want that date format on any machine, any browser, or do you want your date format when you view the page,  what are you using the date for?  if you are filling something in, then how it looks on a browser isn't going to matter, you just use the properties of the object to fill in....whatever

Comment: Note: The `Date` method doesn't return a `DateTime` value without the time part, it returns one where the time is actually `00:00:00`. A `DateTime` value doesn't exist without the time part. Note also that using `new Date()` multiple times is not just ugly, it could give a completely wrong result if you run the code right at midnight so that the date changes from one call to the next. Given, that is extremely unlikely to happen, but it's better to write it so that it can never happen.

Comment: @Guffa As I put in parentheses, I just use the expression `without` to mean the value 00:00:00

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is not ideal, but you can do it this way...

```
var today = new Date();
var dateWithoutTime = new Date(today.getFullYear() , today.getMonth(), today.getDate());
```

There are multiple ways to make Dates in javascript.  The format above will create a new Date based on "today"'s year, month, and date (think day of the month).

Technically you could also do this with a DateString, however "new Date(dateString)" is implementation dependent, and may have inconsistent behavior across different browsers.

And if making 2 Date objects makes you uncomfortable, you could always do the following:

```
var today = new Date();
today.setHours(0); // or today.toUTCString(0) due to timezone differences
today.setMinutes(0);
today.setSeconds(0);
```

Comment: I liked the idea of setting hours min and sec to 0

Answer (score 3):

Your solution can be slightly improved by using a variable:

```
var now = new Date();
var dt = new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth(), now.getDate());
```

However, you can use [Date.js](http://www.datejs.com/), in which case your solution is simple:

```
var dt = Date.today();
```

Read more about it in the [Date.js documentation](http://code.google.com/p/datejs/wiki/APIDocumentation#today), or try it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/s9guc/).

Comment: Good link, but I don't want to use a plugging for this task

Answer (score 0):

[JavaScript Date Object](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_obj_date.asp)

[Mozilla Documentation on `toLocalDateString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString)

this code will give you the date in the format `mm/dd/yyyy` (at least that is what it gave me, because that is my locale convention)

```
var today = new Date(); 
document.write(today.toLocaleDateString());
```

*Note*: `var today = new Date();` is a Date object that has `ToString` Methods for displaying it's `properties`

if your local conventions are to give you `yyyy/mm/dd` then it should give you what you want.  as w3schools says

> `toLocaleDateString` --> Returns the date portion of a Date object as a string, using locale conventions

**Code and Result of another answer doesn't look right to me**

```
var today = new Date();
today.setHours(0); // or today.toUTCString(0) due to timezone differences
today.setMinutes(0);
today.setSeconds(0); document.write(today);
```

This code gives the result of

> Thu Sep 19 2013 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)

in Chrome

my answer gives

> 9/19/2013

because that is my Locale Convention,  if the OP wanted `yyyy/mm/dd` because that is the locale convention then my answer would be correct.

Comment: Note that the OP wants a `Date` object, not a string. And he wants a code shorter than his (even if yours is prettier).

Comment: It's again a string. If I understand right, the OP wants today's date with the time set to 00:00:00.

Comment: quote from the Original Post `This will give the current date, without the TimeSpan value ('00:00:00').`

Comment: Referencing to w3schools on StackOverflow is like begging for downvotes. There are better sources, for example the [Official Mozilla Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg, I know, but I also provided code and explanation to show that the information was correct, and that it worked the way I said it did. I will add a link from that page as well